# Toggle inline mode - jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

jQuery UI datepickers can be inline or popup depending on the type of element they are called on. `<input>` makes them popup and `<div>` or `<span>` makes them inline.

I need a way to toggle them from popup to inline and back without clobbering event listeners and other things that have been coupled to the elements.

As a starting point: [this fiddle is close to my actual environment.](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/uzdbnzwo/4/)
Code that needs changes:

```
var toggle = function(){
    //toggle #StartDate's inline-ness without clobbering it
};

$node.on('click','#toggle',toggle);
```

As you can see, the datepickers are attached to timepickers and eachother through the datepair script. So simply re-instantiating them when they toggle is undesirable.

A CSS solution where I just change `#StartDate`'s class would be ideal but I doubt that's possible.

**EDIT:**
Photo description of what I'm trying to achieve:

I need the toggle button to toggle between the following:

**Inline Mode:**

[image: inline mode]

**Popup Mode:**

[image: popup mode]

Notice how one is always expanded and the other pops up when clicked on. In my fiddle, currently, this would be the difference between the startdate and enddate datepickers.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Nor why you are writing your html in JS and not in the page. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Ramy The fiddle is for making sure the solution doesn't clobber event listeners and such. If you want a simplified one: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/8xbyo5pj/1/

Comment: I think the easiest way is to destroy it and re-init it with `inline: true` .. I don't think you can change that after it was already init ( at least to my knowledge ). Because the behavior is very different.

Comment: hmm. if I can't change it to inline, maybe I can simulate the behavior by hiding the actual datepick, making a visible input the `altField` and setting the `showOn` option to a click event on the altField.

Comment: That can work, I believe. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simulate what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/hzg2ec30/9/

```
/////////////////////
// Makes a datepicker toggleable between inline and an emulated popup mode.
// Returns: function that toggles the datepicker.
// Params:
//  - id of the container
//  - options.datepicker and options.altfield (class names)
//    ^ defaults are .picker and .altfield

var makeToggleable = function (container, options){
    options = typeof options !== 'undefined' ? options :
              {datepicker:".picker",altfield:".altfield"};
    var picker = options.datepicker;
    var altfield = options.altfield;
    var container = container; //in case selector refresh is needed
    var $node = $(container).addClass("datepicker-toggleable");
    var inline = false;
    var open = false;
    var bindOneOutsideMousedown = function(){ 
    // binds one mousedown, rebinds if click was on the picker or altfield
        $(document).one('mousedown',function closeOrBindAgain(e){
            if (inline) {return;}
            var $picker = $node.find(picker);
            if (!$picker.is($(e.target)) // if the target of the click isn't the picker
            && !$(e.target).parents(picker).length // nor a descendant of the picker
            && !$node.find(altfield).is($(e.target))) { // nor the altfield
                open = false;
                $picker.addClass('invisible');
            }else{
                bindOneOutsideMousedown();
            }
        });
    }
    var onAltFieldMousedown = function () { //open picker on altfield click
        if (open||inline) {return;}
        open = true;
        var $picker = $node.find(picker);
        $picker.removeClass("invisible");
        $picker.position({ //move it below the altfield
                my: "left top",
                at: "left bottom",
                of: $node.find(altfield),
                offset: "0 0",
                collision: "none"
        });
        $picker.datepicker('option', 'onSelect',function (e) { //close on date select           
            $(this).trigger( 'change' );
            $picker.datepicker('option', 'onSelect', null); // turn off select listener
            if(!inline){
                $picker.addClass("invisible");
                open = false;
            }
        });
        bindOneOutsideMousedown();
    };
    var toggle = function () {
        inline = !inline;
        if (inline) { //inline mode
            $node.addClass("inline").removeClass("popup");
            $node.find(picker).removeClass("invisible");
            $node.find(altfield).addClass("invisible");
        } else { //popup mode
            open = false;
            $node.removeClass("inline").addClass("popup");
            $node.find(picker).addClass("invisible");
            $node.find(altfield).removeClass("invisible")
            .on('mousedown', onAltFieldMousedown);
        }
    };
    return toggle;
};
```

Usage:

```
$("#StartDate .picker").datepicker({
    altField: ".altfield"
});

var toggleStart = makeToggleable("#StartDate",{altfield:".altfield",datepicker:".picker"}); //makes #StartDate toggleable and returns the function to toggle it

$("#toggle").click('click', toggleStart);
$("#toggle").trigger('click');
```

Basically, it's always an inline but pretends to be a popup when in "popup mode". To be exactly like datepicker's popup mode, it needs some to animate `opacity` rather than being set to `display:none`. Likely some other details as well.

And here it is working with two datepickers in the same container and lots of coupling: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/Lf71gjcc/3/